# Haskell FFI: Successful compile and link, app crash with BEX64

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I am learning how to use the FFI and am starting with a very simple example, calling a C function from Haskell.

This is all under Windows 7, 64-bit, Visual Studio Community 2013.

The C looks like this:

```
_declspec(dllexport) int line(int m, int b, int x) {
    return m * x + b;
}
```

I've set the VS compiler to generate a 64-bit DLL and it does so, one named simpleclib.dll (there's also the matching .lib file, too)

The matching Haskell looks like this:

```
module Main (main) where

foreign import ccall "line" cline :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

main = do
    putStr "hello,world\n"
    putStr (show y)

y = cline 2 5 10
```

GHC was downloaded within the last month, 7.8.3.

The command line for ghc is this:

```
c:\> ghc foreign -L. -lsimpleclib
```

This runs successfully, generating a .EXE as expected.

Running the program produces an app crash on a BEX64:

Problem Event Name:   BEX64
  Application Name: foreign.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    551048a6
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_0981
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Offset: 0000000000000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   0000000000000008
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0981
  Additional Information 2: 09817cdf87ca03322f39545f3e74c62d
  Additional Information 3: 31c0
  Additional Information 4: 31c0a543af0be952ecd86b6ee71cc83a

I've also tried using Data.Int.Int64's for the parameter definition. Same result.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
cww

Comment: Use `CInt`, not `Int`. Not sure if that's the only problem, never tried to link to a windows dll.

Comment: Good thought. Just tried it. Same result. So far, I've tried Int, CInt, Int32, and Int64 thinking that it may be some sort of stack misalignment thing. All give the same result. A slightly deeper look into the debugger reveals that the root problem is an access violation at (of course) 0x0000000000000000 (a 64 bit 0). Strange, because I don't see any obvious adjustment that can be made.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the knob to tell VS to create a 64 bit dll, so I tried gcc (on Win 7, 64 bit). I had to change the first line of your c program in 2 ways, add a `__cdecl`, and made the `_cdecl` have 2 underscores:
  `__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl line(int m, int b, int x) {`

```
C:\...\>foreign
hello,world
25
```

`

Comment: More and more interesting. I'll have to read a little on the switches on gcc and try it, but I have no doubt it will work. So, in VS, to build a 64 bit dll you go into the configuration manager and add x64 as a configuration. So, when I added the second underscore to "__declspec" everything compiled, linked and ran without a crash, except no output was written. Too strange! If I comment out the line that writes out y, then it runs and I get the hello,world message. With the line in, nothing. This at  home machine (still 64 bit Win 7) original example was on at work.

Comment: Update: At work it builds and runs fine with gcc. I have no idea what's up with the Visual Studio compiler/linker.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a bug in `binutils` that VS-generated 64-bit import libraries (`.lib` coming with `.dll`). See the discussion here: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10885#comment:6

The bug can be worked around by replacing binutils in the GHC distribution with the ones from MSys2. Alternatively, the linker usually is able to link the `.dll` files directly, without the `.lib` files. This works for me for small examples but bigger may fail — I do not recommend taking this approach.